# How to get claims from laravel-passport access token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i have implemented laravel passport, i want to get claims array from passport access token.

> is it possible ?? if yes then please suggest solution.

e.g `my-laravel-passport-access-token` will contain following data.

```
{
  "aud": "7",
  "jti": "XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
  "iat": 1568368682,
  "nbf": 1568368682,
  "exp": 1599991082,
  "sub": "2",
  "scopes": [],
  "custom_property": false
}
```

so how to get that data from token ??

Thanks